# How would I order an array in a specific order? Java

Tags: java, java-8

I have input that is sent to my db query:

```
[25,1381,34, ...]
```

My data is then returned from the query, but the db has changed the order of what is returned.

```
[{
    id: 1381,
    name: 'Test'
}, {
    id: 25,
    name: 'Another test'
}, {
    id: 34,
    name: 'One last test'
}, 
...]
```

I want to reorder the data and return to the caller in the order that the id's were sent in.  ie:

```
[{
    id: 25,
    name: 'Another test'
}, {
    id: 1381,
    name: 'Test'
}, {
    id: 34,
    name: 'One last test'
}, 
...]
```

What would be a performant way to reorder the data into the original order?

Comment: Way too little context. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Construct a mapping from the IDs to the position in the input:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
  map.put(ids[i], i);
}
```

Now, construct a `Comparator<YourObject>` which sorts based on this map:

```
Comparator<YourObject> cmp = Comparator.comparing(yo -> map.get(yo.id));
```

Then sort your list using this comparator.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your post, that your main issue is a performant way to get the desired order and assuming that you are dealing with a large scale data, I would map -using a HashMap for best performance- each element of `[25,1381,34,...]` with the value of a 'counter' that is incremented every iteration upon your request ids, then use this mapping to compare different records while sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm getting it wrong, but a way to return the data in the same order could be to create an array which stores the input order `int order[] = new int[inputdb.size()];` if the inputdb is stored as a collection.
Then, save ids. ie:

```
for(int i = 0; i < inputdb.lengh; i++){
    order[i] = inputdb.get(i).getId();
}
```

Finally when data comes out from the db run a comparator or create it by yourself:

```
for(int k = 0; k < inputdb.size(); k++){
    for(int j = 0; j < inputdb.size(); j++){
        if(order[k] == inputdb.get(j).getId()){
            inputdb.set(j,inputdb.get(j); 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`